# How do I get this clock to update every minute with the ticker service?

Tags: pebble-sdk

I am making a super simple watchface for the pebble using SDK 2. The watchface compiles and install but the clock does not update. I have attached my code below. Any ideas?

```
#include <pebble.h>

static Window *s_main_window;
static TextLayer *s_time_layer;
static TextLayer *s_date_layer;

static GFont s_time_font;

static BitmapLayer *s_background_layer;
static GBitmap *s_background_bitmap;


static void update_time() {
  // Get a tm structure
  time_t temp = time(NULL); 
  struct tm *tick_time = localtime(&temp);

  // Create a long-lived buffer
  static char buffer[] = ">00:00";

  // Write the current hours and minutes into the buffer
  if(clock_is_24h_style() == true) {
    //Use 2h hour format
    strftime(buffer, sizeof(">00:00"), ">%H:%M", tick_time);
  } else {
    //Use 12 hour format
    strftime(buffer, sizeof(">00:00"), ">%I:%M", tick_time);
  }

  // Display this time on the TextLayer
  text_layer_set_text(s_time_layer, buffer);
}

static void update_date(){
  time_t temp = time(NULL);
  struct tm *tick_time = localtime(&temp);
  static char buffer[] = ">00/00/00";
  strftime(buffer, sizeof(">00/00/00"), ">%D", tick_time);
  text_layer_set_text(s_date_layer, buffer);
}


static void main_window_load(Window *window) {

  //Create Gbitmap, then set to created bitmap layer
  s_background_bitmap = gbitmap_create_with_resource(RESOURCE_ID_lenny);
  s_background_layer = bitmap_layer_create(GRect(0, 0, 144, 168));
  bitmap_layer_set_bitmap(s_background_layer, s_background_bitmap);
  layer_add_child(window_get_root_layer(window), bitmap_layer_get_layer(s_background_layer));


  // Create time TextLayer
  s_time_layer = text_layer_create(GRect(5, 90, 144, 50));
  text_layer_set_background_color(s_time_layer, GColorClear);
  text_layer_set_text_color(s_time_layer, GColorBlack);
  text_layer_set_text(s_time_layer, ">00:00");


  //Create date TextLayer
  s_date_layer = text_layer_create(GRect(5, 115, 144, 50));
  text_layer_set_background_color(s_date_layer, GColorClear);
  text_layer_set_text_color(s_date_layer, GColorBlack);
  text_layer_set_text(s_date_layer, ">00/00/00");


  //Create GFont
  s_time_font = fonts_load_custom_font(resource_get_handle(RESOURCE_ID_arial25));

  //Apply to TextLayer
  text_layer_set_font(s_time_layer, s_time_font);
  text_layer_set_text_alignment(s_time_layer, GTextAlignmentLeft);

  text_layer_set_font(s_date_layer, s_time_font);
  text_layer_set_text_alignment(s_date_layer, GTextAlignmentLeft);

  // Add it as a child layer to the Window's root layer
  layer_add_child(window_get_root_layer(window), text_layer_get_layer(s_time_layer));
  layer_add_child(window_get_root_layer(window), text_layer_get_layer(s_date_layer));

  // Make sure the time is displayed from the start
  update_time();
  update_date();
}

static void main_window_unload(Window *window) {
  //Unload GFont
  fonts_unload_custom_font(s_time_font);

  // Destroy TextLayer
  text_layer_destroy(s_time_layer);

  //Destroy Gbitmap
  gbitmap_destroy(s_background_bitmap);

  //Destroy BitmapLayer
  bitmap_layer_destroy(s_background_layer);

  //Destroy datelayer
  text_layer_destroy(s_date_layer);
}

static void tick_handler(struct tm *tick_time, TimeUnits units_changed) {
  update_time();
}

  static void tick_handler_date(struct tm *tick_time, TimeUnits units_changed){
  update_date();
}

static void init() {
  // Create main Window element and assign to pointer
  s_main_window = window_create();

  // Set handlers to manage the elements inside the Window
  window_set_window_handlers(s_main_window, (WindowHandlers) {
    .load = main_window_load,
    .unload = main_window_unload
  });

  // Show the Window on the watch, with animated=true
  window_stack_push(s_main_window, true);

  // Register with TickTimerService
  tick_timer_service_subscribe(MINUTE_UNIT, tick_handler);

  tick_timer_service_subscribe(DAY_UNIT, tick_handler_date);
}

static void deinit() {
  // Destroy Window
  window_destroy(s_main_window);
}

int main(void) {
  init();
  app_event_loop();
  deinit();
}
```

There is a true type font being used as well as a png. These can be replaced with anything for testing purposes as long as the reference ID's in the code are changed as well. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It's because you override checking every minute and updating the time here:

```
tick_timer_service_subscribe(DAY_UNIT, tick_handler_date);
```

`tick_timer_service_subscribe` takes a unit and a function pointer. When you called it the second time you overrode the unit and the function pointer.

Instead you should call it once with `MINUTE_UNIT` and `tick_handler`. Then inside `tick_handler` write a new function called `update_date_and_time`. This function does what it says, updates the date and the time. You'll unnecessarily update the date most of the time, but that's okay, because you'll correctly update the time.